# How can I build a pinterest like photo picker with django?

Tags: django, django-models

I am building a django application where users can upload multiple images and store it as an album.

In my current implementation, I have two models `Photo` and `Album`. In the `Album` model I have a many-to-many field to the `Photo` model. Thus, a user can select multiple photos in the `Album` model.

Is there a way by which I can implement a photo picker in `Album` model instead of a simple many-to-many field?

Here is my code:

```
class Photo(models.Model) :
    def get_gallery_path(self, filename):
        ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
        filename = "%s.%s" % (uuid.uuid4(), ext)
        return 'static/uploads/images/gallery/' + filename

    uploader = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    image = ProcessedImageField(default='', verbose_name='Image', upload_to=get_gallery_path,validators=[validate_file_size], **processed_image_field_specs)
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id) + str(self.uploader.username) + str(self.date)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Photos"
        verbose_name = "Photo"


class Album(models.Model) :
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    uploader = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=True)
    photos = models.ManyToManyField(Photo, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Albums"
        verbose_name = "Album"
```

PS: I am only using the built-in admin interface to store data.

Comment: What do you mean by "implement a photo picker in Album model"?

Comment: The photos are displayed like in the gallery of a smart phone, from which we can select photos

Comment: Django and it’s Models has nothing to do with how pictures are displayed on the front end. That’s completely up to the template of HTML, CSS and Javascript.

Comment: No, I meant in the admin page. Like we have the date-picker for DateFields, is there a way / library that makes it possible to display images in the ManyToMany field?